# Response variable is mostly 0s

Tags: multiple-regression, modeling, linear-model

I have a dataset that considers forest fire data from the Montesinho natural park in the Tr´as-os-Montes northeast region of Portugal. The data used in the experiments was collected from January 2000 to December 2003.  The goal is to predict the burned area of forest fires using measureable meteorological and other data.  Can be found here: https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Forest+Fires

[image]

Variable Descriptions:

1. X - x-axis spatial coordinate within the Montesinho park map: 1 to 9
2. Y - y-axis spatial coordinate within the Montesinho park map: 2 to 9
3. month - month of the year: "jan" to "dec"
4. day - day of the week: "mon" to "sun"
5. FFMC - Fine Fuel Moisture Code (FFMC) index from the Fire Weather Index (FWI) system: 18.7 to 96.20
6. DMC - Duff Moisture Code (DMC) index from the FWI system: 1.1 to 291.3
7. DC - Drought Code (DC) index from the FWI system: 7.9 to 860.6
8. ISI - Initial Spread Index (ISI) from the FWI system: 0.0 to 56.10
9. temp - temperature in Celsius degrees: 2.2 to 33.30
10. RH - relative humidity in %: 15.0 to 100
11. wind - wind speed in km/h: 0.40 to 9.40
12. rain - outside rain in mm/m2 : 0.0 to 6.4
13. area - the burned area of the forest (in ha): 0.00 to 1090.84
14. rain2 - binary, is it raining or not?
15. logarea - log transform of area

I want to build a simple linear regression between two continuous variables, and then a multiple regression model.  But I want the response variable in both cases to be Area (which is the Area in ha of land burnt in the recorded fire).

My problem is that most of the values for the area variable have a value of 0, since the recordings were marked as 0 if the value was less than 0.1 hectares. I have used the log transform of this variable as log(area + 1), which does help the distribution.

[image]
[image]

However, when I chose another continuous variable to run a simple linear regression (Temperature), the model fails due to the skew of the response variable.

[image]

[image]

My question is:  are there any other types of transformations that may assist with this problem and allow my model to assume normality?  Also, when I go to create the multiple regression model will the creation of interaction terms and more variables assist with my significance?

Please let me know if I need to clarify any part of my post.

Comment: I think you will want to model as a mixture-distribution rather than try to transform it away.  I suspect the distribution of small fires is radically different from larger fires and what you have is a mixture of an exponential distribution (for small fires) and a gamma distribution (for larger fires).  The mixing proportion then becomes another parameter to be estimated by your predictors (and may prove to be the most interesting parameter).  An alternative would be to split the fires into small fires vs large fires and model that.

Comment: @StatNoodle Interesting, thank you.  When you say "split the fires into small fires vs large fires", do you mean make the variable binary (0=small, 1=big) or do you mean create new variables that contains only big fires and then only small fires?  Then just model them separately?

Comment: I suspect you want a transformation, areas are >0 for any fire that actually occurred. So a log-transformation makes sense. A mixture distribution may be a good idea, but using large or big fire as a predictor, or model them separately seems wrong (it is an outcome and you are presumably interested in what made a fire big or small). The "0 means <0.1" issues is a case of censoring and for the log-normal (LN) distribution the likelihood contribution of "standard" fires is $f_\text{LN}(x_i;\mu_i, \sigma)$ and for such fires of censored size $F_\text{LN}(0.1;\mu_i, \sigma)$.

Comment: You would estimate the mixture parameters:  the exponential mean parameter, the "gaussian" mean and variance parameters, and the mixing probability from the data so you do not decide what constitute "small" versus "large"...the data can do that.  If you can plot the data in better detail, you can see whether a mixture distribution looks like a good fit.  You will need to constrain the "gaussian" mean to be larger than the exponential mean.  And you may need to penalize towards triviality (if there is not a significant number of "small" fires.